# Passing External API to Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, get

I'm working with an external API from Shipstation. I can do a GET request to pull the information in just fine into Nodejs, but I can't figure out how I can transfer that data client-side to manipulate within Angular? I've been struggling with this for a few days now and all my googling searching isn't helping out.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

var Orders = require('./controllers/ordersController');

app.use('/orders', Orders);


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I am live on port 3000');
});
```

**ordersController.js**

```
var request = require('request');

module.export = request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/listbytag?orderStatus=awaiting_shipment&tagId=32099&page=1&pageSize=100',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    }}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
    console.log('Response:', body);
});
```

I figured the best way was to put the GET request in its own "orders" module, export it, and then have angular access that route in an http request (/orders). Sounds good in theory, right?

I appreciate the help in advance! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the ShipStation API provides JSON which is easily consumable by Angular.

You can load the JSON into your Angular app like this:

```
$http.get('/orders:3000', function(data) {
    $scope.Orders = data;
    console.log($scope.Orders);
});
```

Add this to your controller, then check the browser's developer console to see the output.  From there, you can manipulate the JSON object however you need and display the information in your HTML view.